Синонимизировать метки [mask] и [маска]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

mask (44 вопроса)
маска (18 вопросов)

у обеих нет описания
Основная - конечно, маска, т. к. она на русском.
PS: или стоит сделать [маски]?

А что такое маска? По-моему, термин неоднозначен.

@Зонтик неоднозначен, достаточно даже на enSO глянуть. Но это не значит совсем, что [маска] предполагается использовать для чего-то одного, а [mask] для чего-то другого. Специфика может определяться соседними метками в вопросе.

готово!
updating post history, 52 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 44 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 44 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'mask': [mask] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 62
tag remapping of [маска] and [mask] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym mask -> маска was approved!

